# Pass data using jQuery Trigger event to a Change event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to pass data to a `change` event via jQuery's `trigger` method?

The issue here is that a `click` event triggers the upload menu. Once the image is selected, the `change` event is fired, however. The data I passed into the trigger event's second parameter is passed to the click event, not to the change event. In the example below, `data` is undefined.

**Trigger Image Change**

```
$('.change_main_image').live('click', function() {
    $('input[name=photo].change_uploader').trigger('click', ["some string"]);
});
```

**Event Handler**

```
$('input[name=photo].change_uploader').live('change', function (e, data) {
   alert(data); // undefined
   //canvas resize and upload script
});
```

Comment: Why not just directly trigger the change event?

Comment: @TaylorMac can you elaborate? I'm running into this exact same issue and it sounds like it ended up being a non-issue for you. Can you explain what you ended up doing? I need to trigger('click', param) to initiate the upload, but I need param in my change() function. I am getting undefined in the change() function as you indicated in your question.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` like this. And `change` event should be triggered, not `click`

```
$('.change_main_image').on('click', function() {
    $('input[name=photo].change_uploader').trigger('change', [{somedata:true}]);
});


$('input[name=photo].change_uploader').on('change', function (e, data) {
   alert(data.somedata); 
   //canvas resize and upload script
});
```

Comment: And when you need to use .live() because the project was developed in an old version of jquery and your boss tells you that refactoring is not an option... Sad but true.

Comment: Why is that when we pass an array from the trigger point, we get the first element of the array instead of the array itself??