# Can I transfer data between elements with a JavaScript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I’m building a widget system for the web/app creation tool [Weld](https://www.weld.io), and I would like to be able to transfer data between elements on the DOM.

Ideally something like:

```
var myObject = { name: 'Bob', age: 35 };

// Send change event with data
$('#myElement').trigger('change', myObject);

// Listen to change event and receive data
$('#myElement').change(function (event, myObject) {
    console.log('#myElement received', myObject);
});
```

Is something like this possible?

To clarify, the event trigger/receive works but can I somehow transfer `myObject` with the event?

Comment: Yes. Please have a look at jquery trigger api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data using jQuery Trigger event to a Change event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506209/pass-data-using-jquery-trigger-event-to-a-change-event-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Bear in mind that `$.trigger` ends up using `Function.apply` on any listeners, so the additional arguments you pass to trigger need to be in an array:

```
var myObject = { name: 'Bob', age: 35 };

// Send change event with data
$('#myElement').trigger('change', [myObject, 'hi']);

// Listen to change event and receive data
$('#myElement').change(function (event, myObject, someMessage) {
    console.log('#myElement received', myObject, someMessage);
});
```

This is outlined in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/